# Latest AWX version with docker-compose for production

Tags: ansible-awx

Trying to configure AWX runtime using `Docker` with `Docker Compose`. With image `quay.io/ansible/awx:21.7.0` it seems a little tricky. I don't want to set up Kubernetes and use `AWX Operator` - don't have resources and tasks for this complicity, just redundant tools. All I need - it is running Docker process with some additional services in my infrastructure (for example Traefik and SystemD services, AWX one of them).

Does anyone have moving on this way? Trying to find production Dockerfile (I think it uses in prod, right?) and prepare Django environment to work inside docker-compose (env vars, networks, resources, services).

I'll be updating this post with my results. Thanks guys, I hope I'm not alone with this problem.